# How to read XML data in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, oop

Hi i have been trying to read my XML file in my android but have been unsuccessful.
this is my XML file : http://collectionservice.byethost13.com/backup.XML
all i have to do is that there is a row tag in the document and have to show only the IDs in all the row tags inside the Listview of the first screen. 
Can any body give me an example or something will be very thankful.

Hi i just want to show this XML file:

ID on the first screen listview from the XML and then on click on the specific id it goes to the next screen and show ID,Name,Phone,Department,What_Ever of that id.

Can anybody do give me a code or something have to give it to the client today and i am new to android will be very thankful to you.

Man have tried many links but no successes 
Pretty please.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Comment: You might also want to read about securing your web server before posting the address on a public forum.  With about 15 seconds of work, I know a lot about your server.  Just as well I'm a good guy!

Comment: @Simon well thanks for the advice but it is just a test server

Answer (score 1):

Here the official documentation, pretty clear and simple : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 1):

I found that [simple-xml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) is very easy to use to parse xml into objects.

The docs are well written so it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SaxParser to parse XML file in android. Extend DefaultHandler class to read your tags. 
[Find a simple example here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example)